# Does anybody know how to count number of periods since entry?

Tags: algorithmic-trading

How can I count the number of periods since opening a position? Should I start from the current position and backward count the candles with the opening lower than the previous one? Thank you in advance for your help.

```
protected override void OnStart()
    {

        var MyPositions = Positions.FindAll(MyLabel, Symbol);

        foreach (var position in MyPositions){ 

        ... ???

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use built-in method to get bar index `Bars.OpenTimes.GetIndexByTime`

```
var position = Positions[0];
var barIndex = Bars.OpenTimes.GetIndexByTime(position.EntryTime);

if (barIndex == -1)
{
    Print("No bars in history with opening time before the position was opened");
}
else
{
    var barsSinceEntry = Bars.Count - 1 - barIndex;
    Print("Position was opened {0} bar(s) ago", barsSinceEntry);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the number of bars passed after you open a position?
If that what you mean you can use position open time and Bars.OpenTimes.GetIndexByTime to find the bar index when you opened the position, after that you can use the current index of bars minus the position opened bar index to get the total number of bars passed:

```
using cAlgo.API;
using System;

namespace cAlgo.Robots
{
    [Robot(TimeZone = TimeZones.UTC, AccessRights = AccessRights.None)]
    public class PositionBarsPassed : Robot
    {
        [Parameter("Label", DefaultValue = "MyBot")]
        public string Label { get; set; }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            var currentIndex = Bars.Count - 1;

            foreach (var position in Positions)
            {
                if (!string.Equals(position.Label, Label, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) continue;

                var positionOpenBarIndex = Bars.OpenTimes.GetIndexByTime(position.EntryTime);

                var numberOfBarsPassedSincePositionOpened = currentIndex - positionOpenBarIndex;

                Print(numberOfBarsPassedSincePositionOpened);
            }
        }
    }
}
```